# What Happens To MSMQ When Network Connection Lost

Tags: msmq

If I am using MSMQ over the web, what happens if the network connection is lost between client and server?

So can you still add messages to the Queue, and if so where are they stored? In the client app, or in the clients OS etc?

For instance if I have a windows service which is adding items to a queue in a different country. What if the network connection is lost, and the windows service is restarted. Do the messages get lost forever?

The other part of the question relates to the route that a message takes, is it sent directly to the receiving queue, or is it written into a queue on the client side? Does that require MSMQ to be installed on the sending server, and how about licensing for that?

Is there any good documentation to explain the required setup?

Comment: No, the point of MSMQ is that this does not cause loss of data.  They are stored on disk.

Comment: Note - Only recoverable and transactional messages are stored on disk; express messages, on the other hand, will NOT survive a reboot. Message storage is configurable; default is system32\msmq\storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Regarding your follow up question. Yes you have to install msmq on the sending server. There aren't any licensing cost, because MSMQ is part of windows and not a separate software (just like the IIS). Here is documentation on "[Setting Up a Message Queue](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684791.aspx)" on windwos 2003.

**Before Update:** Outgoing message are stored in the outgoing queue of the sending server. They are not lost if the sending service is restarted. They will wait in the outgoing queues ( which can be inspected with the msmq manager ) for I don't know how long.

if the msmq service or the sending server are restarted. Then "express" messages will be lost. express or recoverable are properties of non-transcriptional messages.

Comment: OK, so does that mean you have to install MSMQ on the sending server as well? Are there licensing costs for this? Is there any good documentation around to explain this setup?

Comment: This demo is good http://bit.ly/iPJTrq. I installed it on two machines, both have to have MSMQ installed. Messages go on the outgoing queue automatically and are taken off when the receiving server receives them. These outgoing queues are created dynamically as needed. All this just happens seamlessly to the application.